# SSRS Multi-Value Parameter Resets when running the report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SQL stored procedure that I call from my SSRS report with a multi-value parameter named "Category".  When I run the report in SSRS selecting "Select ALL" the report runs fine, but after deploying the report and running it through reporting services, after entering the Start and Ending date and selecting All (Category) value, the Category Select All resets after clicking view report.

Below is the declaration of the parameter in SQL
`@Start DATETIME=NULL,@End DATETIME=NULL,@Category VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL`

Then in the query I used the Split function for the comma delimeter`AND NoteCategory IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Category,','))`

Then in SSRS I added `=Join(Parameters!Category.Value,",")` in the Dataset Paremeters. So, I'm not sure what is wrong with my report because it runs fine in the development platform, but after deploying the Category multi value parameter fails.

Comment: Have you tried removing the default `NULL` value in your SQL? For instance just declare the variable and type - `DECLARE @Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME,@Category VARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: Then NULL value in the declaration of variable is used to blank out the value of parameter when loaded, I did remove it and it still same issue . thanks.